# FPS Lock for HTML Canvas/Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, frame-rate

I've been attempting to do a frame by frame animation with a spritesheet I made on a HTML website and I could not figure out how to lock the fps for the animation. The issue is it's always going at lightning speeds, and I want to be able to lock it at ~ 10-15 fps
I have tried using the Date.now() method, and the setInterval method but it doesn't seem to be working for the time being.

The way I am using this animation is also reliant on checking an array to make sure that it should commit to animating the 4 frame animation that I made.
Here's the code I've been using.

```
function animateCharacter() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("portrait");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var character = new Image();
    character.src = "/assets/spritesheet.jpg";
    animate();
    function animate() {

        context.drawImage(character, shift, 0, width, height, 300, 0, width / 2, height / 2);

        if (currentFrame == totalFrames) {
            shift = 0;
            currentFrame = 0;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setTimeout

```
 function animate(){
// do your animation
//     workout your frame rate
  setTimeout(animate, 500);
 };
 animate();
```